# Cannot access geth and the browser returns {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

When I try to start my geth node, I use the command as below:

```
geth --identity "MyEtherum" --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "D:\Geth\chain" --port "30303" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" -- networkid 95518 console --dev
```

Then it stopped at this place

[image]

I checked localhost:8545, it returns as below:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

Comment: Just a note that there is a space between `--` and `networkid` and that the `--dev` option will not get used if it is specified after the `console` parameter. Can you please provide the instruction you use to execute your JSON-RPC command.

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured it out!  This problem has troubled me for a long time.      The instruction? Do you mean how I check the json? If so, I just visited "localhost:8545" by chrome.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Glad you figured it out and please feel free to post your own answer (and then mark it as accepted the next day).

Answer (score 1):

this is normal to get such message, because you don't send any data to your rpc server when you visit the localhost:8545.
to check instead use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=en) extension or Curl. (you will find a set of command to use [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)).

Curl :

e.g curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545

Postman :

Choose post methode in the url input and past the following data as raw data  under body onglet as shown in the picture bellow :

[image]